# FBSession openActiveSessionWithReadPermissions not working with system Facebook account entered on iOS7

Tags: ios, facebook, ios7

I'm running the following code to login with facebook:

```
[FBSession openActiveSessionWithReadPermissions:@[@"public_profile, email, user_friends"]
                                           allowLoginUI:YES
                                      completionHandler:
         ^(FBSession *session, FBSessionState state, NSError *error) {

         NSLog(@"fb token: %@", session.accessTokenData.accessToken);

             if(error) {
                 NSLog(@"error: %@", error);
              }
}];
```

When iOS does not have a Facebook account, it works fine. However if there is an account tied to the system, it results in this error:

```
fb token: (null)
error: Error Domain=com.facebook.sdk Code=2 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (com.facebook.sdk error 2.)" UserInfo=0x10eb2b5c0 {com.facebook.sdk:ErrorLoginFailedReason=com.facebook.sdk:SystemLoginCancelled, com.facebook.sdk:ErrorInnerErrorKey=Error Domain=com.apple.accounts Code=7 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (com.apple.accounts error 7.)", com.facebook.sdk:ErrorSessionKey=<FBSession: 0x10ec879b0, state: FBSessionStateClosedLoginFailed, loginHandler: 0x0, appID: 448248105305258, urlSchemeSuffix: , tokenCachingStrategy:<FBSessionTokenCachingStrategy: 0x10eb2ab80>, expirationDate: (null), refreshDate: (null), attemptedRefreshDate: 0001-12-30 00:00:00 +0000, permissions:(null)>}
2014-07-03 21:40:53.410 Tag Beta copy[62878:60b]
```

## **EDIT:**

After updating the Facebook SDK to 3.15.1, it now just bypasses the system account and authenticates through the app. This is definitely better than just error-ing out every time, but it would be better if it presented the UIAlertView asking for the users permission.

The app ID is in the settings page of the Facebook account, and the facebook account is not in sandbox mode. Here is a screenshot of the facebook account:

[image]

Any help to resolve this error would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Why does it say "UNAVAILABLE" in your Facebook settings?  The error says it was cancelled...

Comment: @Fosco I screenshotted this form the simulator, but I am seeing the same issue on the phone